# Reminder email Workflow Help

Tags: 2010, workflow, calendar

I'm looking to create a calender workflow in sharepoint 2010. I want the workflow to send an email to people regarding a calendar event. I would like the email to be sent 7 days before the event is due. Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Are all events going to be created well in advance? Like before 1 week or 2?

Answer (score 2):

With limited details in question, I am assuming few things. First all events will be created well in advance at least more than a week before, second you will be using OOB Start Time field of Calendar list.

So to create a workflow which sends an email before 7 days of an event we need to take following steps.

**1.** Based on the Start Time calculate the Date which is 7 days before the event and store it in a `variable`. We can achieve this using `Add Time to Date` action.

[image]

**2.** Now once we get hold of a date and time which is 7 days before an event, we would want to pause the workflow till that date. And we can achieve this by using `Pause Until Date` action.

[image]

**3.** After workflow finishes its pausing action, We can now send an email to desired person or a group using `Send an Email` action.

[image]

I hope this is helpful!!

Comment: Thank you Asad, that worked perfectly. I was able to test this working with different times and everything is working perfectly. Thanks very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

If you are not willing to use complex SharePoint Workflows, the possibilities are quite limited. For example, triggering a reminder email when the Active Date is approaching in X days, becouse working with approaching or overdue dates is not possible with regular SharePoint functionality. 
So I would recommend you to use 3rd party tool to save your time and use the solution in more other situations: 
http://blog.enovapoint.com/post/Reminding-HR-on-expiring-documents-in-SharePoint